# How to return inside gtest?

Tags: c++, googletest

I am adding couple of tests using google test for the program(C++). For one case, I noticed there is a dependency on database for that test to proceed, so looks like it passes sometimes and failed at other times.

I am thinking of doing something like:

```
TEST_F(DependentClass, aTest)
{
    if(database is opened successfully)
    {
        // Do the checks here
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement something like this for gtest? Or any other way to tackle this issue?

I know mocking the database can be one of the approach, but I'm keeping it as a last solution.

Comment: Mocking the database is the best way. Failing if some dependency is unavailable, like you have now, seems like second best. You could also make the test succeed in this case, but then how will you know if your test is ever being run?

Comment: Mocking or not mocking show what type of test you have: in the first case you have a unit test and with the second—integration. So choose what your test is and proceed further accordingly.

Comment: IMO, if your database does not open successfully, your test should fail.